# Inserting data of type String in Array within object which is in another array

Tags: meteor

How can I insert data of type String in array within object which is in another array?

The below is my array:

```
productRequirements: [{
    question: "What type of Business Bag do you need?",
    type: "checkbox",
    specifications: [
        "Luggage Bag",
        "Handbag",
        "Shoulder Bag",
        "Soft Bag",
        "Laptop Bag",
        "Tote Bag",
        "Not Sure",
        "Others"]
}, {
    question: "What kind of logo do you prefer on your bag?",
    type: "radio",
    specifications: [
        "OEM",
        "Embossed",
        "Debossed",
        "Printed",
        "Customized",
        "Not Sure",
        "Others"]
}]
```

I want to insert strings in `specifications`  one by one and I am trying the following code:

```
Products.update({
    _id: productId,
    "productSpecifications.Specification": listing["Specification"]
}, {
    $push: {
        "productSpecifications.$.Options": {
            Options: listing["Options"]
        }
    }
})
```

which is inserting object instead of string. How can I rectify it?

Comment: You need to specify the array index like this `productSpecifications.1.Options` replace `$` with the array index

Comment: I have added a problem statement at the top as every question should begin with one, improved the formatting of the code blocks and corrected capitalization mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is an extra set of curly braces around `Options:listing["Options"]`.  The current command is telling it to push an object to the options list.

Perhaps try this instead

```
Products.update({_id:productId,"productSpecifications.Specification":listing["Specification"]},
                    {$push: { "productSpecifications.$.Options": listing["Options"]
                }})
```

Also - if `listing["Options"]` is an array, $push will push the whole array as a single object, in which case you should use $each with $push:

```
{$push: {field: {$each: [value1, value2]}}}
```

Also - consider using `$addToSet` instead of `$push` where you want to maintain unique array elements.  `$addToSet` also works with `$each`

```
{$addToSet: {field: {$each: [value1, value2]}}}
```

Hope this helps, be sure to let me know!